# Cocoa Audio / QTKit [play/pause toggle button] (error)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm using this [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/BuildingaSimpleMediaPlayerApplication/BuildingaSimpleMediaPlayerApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008155-CH3-SW8) to make a simple audio player which involves using the QTKit framework, although I can't figure figure out how to make a 'toggle' play/pause button instead of two separate buttons.

I've tried using the following code and it doesn't work, the error message is: (Statement requires expression of scalar type ('void' invalid)

```
- (IBAction)togglePlayback:(id)sender;
{
    if([self play])
    {
        [self stop];
    }
    else
    {
        [self play];
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, or if there is a better way to have an audio track play when the application opens with a toggle 'play/pause' switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like [self play] doesn't return YES or NO. You could go for an instance variable  (e.g. isPlaying) which you are toggling. 
Btw - If you are targeting 10.7 lion or iOS you could go for AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer which is a bit newer API.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do you by chance have any code samples (or class examples) I could reference for the AVFoundation Framework for OS X? The only thing I see on the Apple developer portal are iOS related.

Comment: [There](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAudioPlayer) is the class reference. Implementing is just straight forward. `player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"default.wav"] error:&error]; [player play]`